# Use Calendar object in java as parameter for SQL Server date column?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a project that needs to work on both Oracle and SQL Server. It currently runs on Oracle, and my job is to make queries compatible for Oracle and SQL Server.

The Oracle database has a table with a column called `study_date` which has `DATE` type. So in Java code, I create parameter like this:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(event.getTime()); //returns long value of time
parameters.addValue("study_date", calendar);
...
...
return parameters;
```

This works and insert a row with given time. However, if I run the same code with SQL Server, it doesn't work. I found there are many date types in SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver15, but none of the types work with `Calendar` object in java.

I was able to insert a row by creating `Timestamp` using `Calendar` object I created. It works, but that means I have to write two different sets of code for Oracle and SQL Server. I can, but I am looking for the best way to handle this.